# Executing email sending php script with cron

Tags: php, cron, swiftmailer, mailer

I have a php script that sends an email with an attachment. When I manually execute the php script below via a web browser, everything works well and the email is sent instantly. However, when I try to execute the php file using a crontab command, the email is not sent. Any idea why this is? The cron command isn't generating any errors...

Further, the `email_output.log` shows **success** but the email doesn't come through, as if it is piling up in the outgoing box but never actually sent.

Crontab command:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/bin/php  /my/path/emailApp.php  > /my/path/email_console.log 2> /my/path/email_error.log
```

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php

include_once(__DIR__ . '/mailer/swift_required.php');

$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('mail.myhost.com', 25)
    ->setUsername('name@myhost.com')
    ->setPassword('password');

// Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

$mailTo = Array('testemail@gmail.com');

$subject ="report";
$attach = 'report.pdf';

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance($subject)
  ->setFrom(array('name@mydomain.com' => 'Bob Dole' ))
  ->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath($attach)->setFilename($attach))
  ->setTo($mailTo);


$message->setBody("attached",'text/html');


// Send the message
$result = $mailer->send($message);

if($result == 0){
    echo 'Error';
} else {
    echo 'Success';
}
```

Comment: In your cron make sure the output is being logged some where then check your log.  Most likely: path isn't set, PHP command line not installed or PHP command line uses a different INI file that prevents it from running

Comment: The issue isn't php related as I have other php crons running successfully. Also, it isnt a path issue as I have successful crons running from the same path.

Comment: Hi @AnchovyLegend did you solve your email and cron job issue? I am having the same issue with no luck!